# Strip html tags, css and js code from string

Tags: javascript, string, strip-tags

I am using `document.documentElement.textContent.toLowerCase()` to read a website text content, the problem is this website has so many css and js code before any real text that I don't even get the complete text, it gets trunked in some part of the css.

How can I remove all the css and js code to retrieve only the text content?

Comment: maybe a sample source will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Yea that works for this site, but does ALL the websites have a body tag?

Comment: @gtilx If they are valid HTML, then yes.

Comment: Most modern browsers will probably nonetheless make it automagically available. <- untested claim

Comment: Wrong. `<!doctype html><title>t</title>foo` is a perfectly legal html document. The resultant DOM will of course have root, `head`, and `body` elements, but they are implied and don't need to have specified in the markup's source.

Comment: @adlwalrus you are talking about something else. I said it won't validate as in the W3C HTML validator service. At the time of posting, I didn't consider the HTML5 doctype.